Microservices X axis scaling - process DB records
Say I have a simple Spring boot microservice that owns a single database table.
On this table I have to do some heavy processing once a day. Say processing means calculate something and then mark the record as completed (UPDATE in the table). Each record has to be processed separately - so no global transaction : roll all records back if one fails.
If the volume of data is light a simple solution is to just restrict the microservice to one instance, select each record separately, process it and update it into the database.

As the volume of data increases I can select multiple records at the same time (say, first 10), split them into different threads, each thread updating its record at completion. After the batch is completed, select next batch of records until all are done. We are still talking about  one instance microservice.

But, as the volume increases, I will arrive at a point where one instance is just not powerful enough and will have to scale up the number of microservice instances.
This is my issue. How can I parallelize the processing between different instances of the same microservice and also make sure the different instances are not processing the same records multiple times ?


Use Spring Batch which can handle this for you. Don't reinvent the wheel. Spring Batch can use partitions (either local or remote) to offload the work. Also I would first look into speeding up with a single node as that is a lot easier, things like processors assigned, memory, JDBC fetch size, writing proper queries and indexes are often quick gains without introducing more complexity.

@M.Deinum I will look into Spring Batch partitions. Thanks !
